# How do you find the selected Speech Language in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, locale, text-to-speech

Is there a way in WP8 to determine either

- The selected Speech Language
- The Users selected locale information

I want to use the most appropriate language to use when using the SpeechSynthesizer class for Text to Speech

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207057%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) by default, the `SpeechSynthesizer` class will default the whatever the user has selected in the settings.

> After you create a Windows.Phone.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer object, you can specify the language of a voice to load. A Windows.Phone.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer instance can load any voice that is installed on the phone and use it to generate speech. If no language is specified, the API will load a voice that matches the language that the user selected in Settings/Speech on the phone.